Robot Framework Selenium - Edge starts, but doesn't open website
I have a rather specific problem I'm currently facing. I'm working in a virtual environment and I'm trying to run a test with Selenium in Edge. All that I am currently trying to do is to open Edge and go to Google.com:
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Test Teardown     Close All Browsers
*** Test Cases ***
Open Google in Edge
    Set Log Level    debug
    Open Browser     https://www.google.com    Edge
    Set Log Level    info

As far as I am aware I'm not doing anything strange, but I keep on getting these errors:
[15452:15508:1202/141313.807:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(523)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:
[15452:15508:1202/141419.321:ERROR:feature_processor_state.cc(42)] Processing error occured: model EdgeUserTopicOnUrlProtobuf failed with CustomInputError, message: 
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50997): Read timed out. (read timeout=120)

The driver is found during the test execution, so that is not the problem.
I have tried the following things:

I thought it would have to do with Edge in some way as it is managed by the organization, so I downloaded the latest version and made sure that the driver version matches the Edge version.
I tried running it in Incognito window.
I tried making an alias and then use the keyword Switch Browser.
I tried just replacing the standard browser that is opened in Selenium to Edge instead of Firefox.
I tried the Browserlibrary. That didn't work due to npm not properly being installed (while in fact the process of installation was correct).
I tried the Create Webdriver keyword. That just didn't work as I could not properly use the keyword.
Making a custom keyword to open Edge that can communicate with Selenium.


In my experience, when this happens the driver version doesn't match the browser version. Double check this. I know you said you did, but you probably should delete all instances of the Edge driver off of your machine then download the right version and use it. There are many times when Selenium grabs the driver from a different place than you expect it to.

True. I was well aware of this being a thing, so I redownloaded Edge and the edgedriver. However, even now they match exactly the problem isn't solved. It could have to do with the VDI at the client prohibiting me from accessing certain elements of Edge in the background, i.e. I cannot access the browser code inspector to look at elements in Edge.

The error of EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed can be ignored and it won't affect the automation.
The real cause is ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50997): Read timed out. (read timeout=120). It is a connection issue. Since you are managed by your organization, certain connection (most related to Python) could have been blocked. You may need to check the connection problem with your administrator.

Does the issue only occur with Edge?
Chrome, Firefox or any other browser works fine?
Nevertheless, I found this: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/49
Someone stated:
You need to delete the old msedgedriver.exe file and download the version matches your Edge
So if you have that file, maybe that is causing the error?
And someone else stated:
Updating the webdriver with the lastest version solved my issue.
ISSUE: "EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I tried all of these steps. Unfortunately without any success. I think it might be due to the VDI that the client is using. At least, it has something to do with it: On my private environment with exactly the same setup and keywords, it works flawless.
